# Outgoing email address on server with Plesk

Tags: php, email, plesk, spf, virtual-server

I have Plesk with a Network Solutions virtual server.  When my site sends out emails using PHP, the email header indicates that the message is coming from an address like this one:

> anonymous@002a1c9.netsolvps.com

How do I change this address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the PHP mail() command, you can set the envelope from address using the -f command, and you can include the from address in the message headers as well, like so:

```
    $to = "to@to.com";
    $from = "from@from.com";
    $subject = "subject";
    $message = "this is the message body";

    $headers = "From: $from"; 
    $ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from);
```